# brew install pianobar failed

Tags: mojave, install, homebrew

I'm trying to install pianobar on my Macbook with the brew package installer. These are the errors I get:

```
Error: pianobar: Failed to download resource "libvorbis"`
Download failed: Homebrew-installed curl is not installed for: https://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/libvorbis-1.3.7.tar.xz
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Using a 2015 MBP with MacOS Mojave.

**UPDATE**
I ran `brew install curl` and ran the pianobar installer again. This time get a new error:

```
==> cmake --build builddir
Last 15 lines from /Users/Josh2/Library/Logs/Homebrew/highway/02.cmake:
/tmp/highway-20230910-36601-ezm3g0/highway-1.0.7/hwy/ops/x86_256-inl.h:5781:33: error: use of undeclared identifier '_knot_mask8'
_mm256_maskz_cvttpd_epu32(_knot_mask8(MaskFromVec(v).raw), v.raw)};
^
In file included from /tmp/highway-20230910-36601-ezm3g0/highway-1.0.7/hwy/per_target.cc:20:
In file included from /tmp/highway-20230910-36601-ezm3g0/highway-1.0.7/hwy/foreach_target.h:127:
In file included from /tmp/highway-20230910-36601-ezm3g0/highway-1.0.7/hwy/per_target.cc:21:
In file included from /tmp/highway-20230910-36601-ezm3g0/highway-1.0.7/hwy/highway.h:410:
/tmp/highway-20230910-36601-ezm3g0/highway-1.0.7/hwy/ops/x86_512-inl.h:4947:33: error: use of undeclared identifier '_knot_mask8'
_mm512_maskz_cvttpd_epu32(_knot_mask8(MaskFromVec(v).raw), v.raw)};
^
4 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hwy.dir/hwy/per_target.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hwy.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you also check for compatibility?  Mojave isn't listed.  https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pianobar.  If this is the case, you need to check with the dev.

Comment: @Allan good point. But pianobar is a command line client, so shouldn't it work regardless of OS ?  Brew and Mojave may be the issue. I'll try using Macports installer instead.

Answer (score 3):

[Homebrew in general](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) and the [pianobar formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pianobar) don‘t support Mojave.

I ended up installing it with Macports instead.

Comment: **Homebrew** doesn't support Mojave.  When it breaks, you get to keep all the pieces.

Comment: Mojave is less than 5 years old. I guess in mac years that's ancient since there have innumerable (debatably retrograde) macos versions released since. Some people have old computers that can't be updated. What I don't get is why would packages build fine when Mojave was still supported, yet now I can't even use brew to install ffmpeg because this "highway" breaks the install. Shouldn't the last known working path be archived? If I could brew install ffmpeg in 2018, why not now?

Comment: @John please have a look at brew.sh, the topic probably has been discussed and explained at length there.

Comment: @John Homebrew supports up to $CURRENT - 2 versions of macOS.  Right now that would be Ventura, Monterey, and Big Sur.  So Mojave is not supported.  If it works, yay you, but like I said, if it breaks, you get to keep all the pieces.